# InvalidOperationException thrown after trying to display a form

Tags: vb.net

I have a separate form that needs to display an image then fade out and open the main form. When it gets to the Form1.Show() part it throws InvalidOperationException. Here's my code:

```
Public Class SPLASH
    Public Declare Auto Function AnimateWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal time As Integer, ByVal flags As Integer) As Boolean
    Public Enum AnimateStyles
        Slide = 262144
        Activate = 131072
        Blend = 524288
        Hide = 65536
        Center = 16
        HOR_Positive = 1
        HOR_Negative = 2
        VER_Positive = 4
        VER_Negative = 8
    End Enum
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        AnimateWindow(Me.Handle, 1000, AnimateStyles.HOR_Negative Or AnimateStyles.Blend)
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Found no fix online for my problem and I couldn't fix it myself either. I look at the documentation but I think i may need to wait for the AnimateWindow function to be fully over or something but I don't know how.

Comment: Without the actual error message it is hard to help.

Comment: By the way the `time` and `flags` parameters of `AnimateWindow` should be of type `UInteger`. You should not use `Declare Function ... Lib` statements because it exists only for backwards compatibility, and most of those that you find online are only compatible with VB6 and not VB.NET. [**DllImport**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is the way to go these days. You can look for C# declarations and convert them using an online converter.

Answer (score -1):

Found an answer!

I created a function

```
Private Sub Done(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal Event As System.EventArgs)
    Dim MainForm As New Form1()
    MainForm.Show()
End Sub
```

And added the following code before

```
 Dim pr As New Process
        pr.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        AddHandler pr.Exited, AddressOf Done
```

After which I put my usual code. 
:)

Comment: What? How would creating a process that you never use work?

Comment: the answer is that I'm using it :D